# ember - rendering model hasMany attribute

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

Hello and thanks for taking the time to help me with my question.

I am having difficulties rendering an attribute of a model using handlebars. Here is the code:

```
App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    teams: DS.hasMany('team', {async: true})
    // teamEffort: DS.attr('array')
});

App.Team = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    project: DS.belongsTo('project')
});

App.Team.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Team 1',
        project: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Team 1',
        project: 2
    },
...]

App.Project.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Project 1 - Test',
        teams: ['1', '3']      
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Project 2 - Test',
        teams: ['2', '4', '5']
    }
...
];
```

and have the following html:

```
...
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="projects">
        <!-- TODO: add css classes -->
        Test
        {{#each project in model}}
            {{#each team in project.teams}}
                aaaaaaa
            {{/each}}
        {{/each}}
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <th colspan="4">Project Name</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{#each project in model}}
                    <tr>
                        {{#each team in project.teams}}
                            aaaa
                        {{/each}}
                        <td colspan="4">{{project.name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                {{/each}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>
...
```

application.js:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('projects', {path: '/'});
});
```

router.js:

```
App.ProjectsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('project');
    }
});
```

When debugging using the Ember Chrome plugin I can see that the projects are associated with 2 and 3 teams accordingly, which is correct, however, when I run {{ log project.teams.length }} I always get 0. I suspect it has got something to do with the fact that I have added the attribute async:true in the model above, however, without it my code would not run.

project.name prints out as expected. I cannot get a reference to the nested relation teams.

I have been banging my head against this for 3 and a half hours now. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Comment: The log only runs while rendering the first time, so it's likely to always be 0 each time, have you tried doing the  each without the table structure? (or putting the team one in the tr?)

Comment: Yes I have.. I have tried almost everything there is to do.. Still I keep getting: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null" :/

Comment: @kingpin2k, I've updated the html with your recommendation, no effect

Comment: What about adding `async: true` to `DS.belongsTo('project')`?

Comment: @claptimes, tried that aswell. I keep getting the same error! :/

Comment: Sorry, I should have noticed the coercion problem earlier, it was 3am tho, so I'm not too torn up over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixture adapter doesn't coerce ids, make sure your id types match (aka "1" != 1) (the rest adapter does coerce).

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/78/edit

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this question. I still havent been able to find a solution for this.. I've tried removing the quotes around the ids aswell.. Did not work :/

Comment: I see that your fiddle example works but locally i still keep getting the same "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null" error, even after including the libraries that you used in the fiddle example...

Comment: I do not have a custom controller.

Comment: Ok I just realised what the problem was. I was using bootstrap.js to beautify my tables and that was messing everything up. Because of your efforts I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: this is funny, I have kind of the same issue, I stopped working on it, but I took a few more hours today to work on it. And @Dragan your solution to stop using tables fixes my problem, WTF. Thanks for that, I'll try to find another way to show the data.

Comment: Something is wrong with bootstrap table and ember handlebar, I also faced same issue.